# Pushwoosh custom data - use to load query page

Tags: ios, cordova, pushwoosh

I am using PhoneGap build + jQuery Mobile (1.4+) with this plugin: http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/

It works all fine for me, what I want to do though is be able to send a jQuery mobile URL (example #test) in custom data which is sent as 'JSON'? Then jQuery Mobile will load the jQuery Page in the app.

Could someone show me how I could implement this? At this stage I have:

```
//push notifications handler
document.addEventListener('push-notification', function(event) {
            var notification = event.notification;
            // navigator.notification.alert(notification.aps.alert);

            //to view full push payload
            // navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(notification));

            //reset badges on icon
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(0);
          });
```

http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/

Their example is  {"key" : "value"} so assume mine is {"url" : "#test"}

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

i hope this still relevant (or for future searches), you can retrieve the data from the  notification.u object

example:

```
if( typeof(notification.u.url) != "undefined" ) {

    // do whatever here

    }
```